How do I correctly render a form from a custom WordPress block in the front-end UI?
I have written a plugin for a custom form block for Gutenberg that should save submissions to a custom post type. The aim is to have authors complete a form with fields for their name, email, book/manuscript title, a drop-down select for genre, some text box summaries and a file upload.
The main issues are:

the block renders properly in the editor but and on the UI depending
on the theme being used. GoDaddy's  Go theme for example, does not
render the select box correctly in that it doesn't show the default
"Select genre".

the drop down select does not retain the selected option either in
the editor or the UI giving the error log message from the script:
"form-block.js? Meta data or selected genre not loaded"

and, while the custom post type is created and accessible in the WP
admin, on loading the front-end the browser console error logs "Post
type not loaded yet"


Everything seems properly enqueued in the php but I cannot determine why the script is not seeing the custom post type or what prevents the drop down list from retaining the selected value.
Any guidance will be appreciated.
EDIT: I have solved items 1 (changed theme) and 3 but #2 is not resolved as the select field still does not retain the option chosen. The updated JavaScript is below.


// Import necessary WordPress packages
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = wp.element;
const { TextControl, SelectControl, TextareaControl, Button, FormFileUpload, Spinner } = wp.components;
const { useEntityProp } = wp.coreData;
const { useDispatch } = wp.data;

// Main Form Component
const FormComponent = () => {
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [summary, setSummary] = useState('');
    const [marketing, setMarketing] = useState('');
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
    const [isPostTypeLoaded, setIsPostTypeLoaded] = useState(false);
    const isPostTypeReadyRef = useRef(false);
    const { editPost } = useDispatch('core/editor');

    const [meta, setMeta] = useEntityProp('postType', 'manuscript', 'meta');

    useEffect(() => {
        const checkPostType = async () => {
            const manuscripts = await wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'manuscript');
            if (manuscripts || manuscripts === null) {
                setIsPostTypeLoaded(true);
                isPostTypeReadyRef.current = true;
            }
        };
        checkPostType();
    }, []);

    const handleGenreChange = (value) => {
        setMeta({ ...meta, _selectedGenre: value });
    };

    if (!isPostTypeLoaded) {
        return wp.element.createElement(Spinner, { key: 'loadingSpinner' }, 'Loading...');
    }

    return wp.element.createElement(
        'form',
        {
            className: 'manuscript-submission-form',
            method: 'POST',
            action: formBlockData.adminPostUrl,
            encType: 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        wp.element.createElement('h2', {}, 'Submit Your Manuscript'),
        wp.element.createElement(TextControl, {
            key: 'firstName',
            label: 'First Name',
            value: firstName,
            onChange: (value) => setFirstName(value),
            name: 'first_name',
            required: true,
        }),
        wp.element.createElement(TextControl, {
            key: 'lastName',
            label: 'Last Name',
            value: lastName,
            onChange: (value) => setLastName(value),
            name: 'last_name',
            required: true,
        }),
        wp.element.createElement(TextControl, {
            key: 'email',
            label: 'Email Address',
            type: 'email',
            value: email,
            onChange: (value) => setEmail(value),
            name: 'email',
            required: true,
        }),
        wp.element.createElement(TextControl, {
            key: 'title',
            label: 'Manuscript Title',
            value: title,
            onChange: (value) => setTitle(value),
            name: 'title',
            required: true,
        }),
        wp.element.createElement(SelectControl, {
            key: 'genre',
            label: 'Genre',
            value: meta?._selectedGenre || '', 
            options: [
                { label: 'Select Genre', value: '' },
                { label: 'Fiction', value: 'fiction' },
                { label: 'Non-fiction', value: 'non-fiction' },
                { label: 'Science Fiction', value: 'sci-fi' },
                { label: 'Fantasy', value: 'fantasy' },
            ],
            onChange: handleGenreChange,
            name: 'genre',
        }),
        wp.element.createElement(TextareaControl, {
            key: 'summary',
            label: 'Manuscript Summary',
            value: summary,
            onChange: (value) => setSummary(value),
            name: 'summary',
            required: true,
        }),
        wp.element.createElement(TextareaControl, {
            key: 'marketing',
            label: 'Marketing Suggestions',
            value: marketing,
            onChange: (value) => setMarketing(value),
            name: 'marketing',
        }),
        wp.element.createElement(FormFileUpload, {
            key: 'fileUpload',
            accept: "image/jpeg, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
            onChange: (event) => setFile(event.target.files[0]),
            multiple: false,
            name: 'manuscript_file',
            children: 'Upload Manuscript',
        }),
        file ? wp.element.createElement('p', {}, `Selected file: ${file.name}`) : null,
        wp.element.createElement('input', {
            type: 'hidden',
            name: 'manuscript_nonce',
            value: formBlockData.manuscriptNonce
        }),
        wp.element.createElement(
            'div',
            { style: { textAlign: 'right', marginTop: '20px' } },
            wp.element.createElement(Button, {
                isPrimary: true,
                type: 'submit',
            }, 'Submit')
        )
    );
};

// Register the block
registerBlockType('authors-form/manuscript-submission-form', {
    title: 'Manuscript Submission Form',
    icon: 'smiley',
    category: 'common',

    edit: () => {
        return wp.element.createElement(FormComponent);
    },

    save: () => null // Dynamic block; rendered by PHP callback
});

// Front-end mounting
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const formContainer = document.getElementById('manuscript-submission-form');
    if (formContainer) {
        const { createRoot } = wp.element;
        createRoot(formContainer).render(wp.element.createElement(FormComponent));
    }
});



Registration of the _selectedGenre post meta property.
<?php

register_post_meta('manuscript', '_selectedGenre', [
    'type'              => 'string',
    'single'            => true,
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
    'show_in_rest'      => true,
    'auth_callback'     => function () {
        return current_user_can('edit_manuscripts');
    }
]);



No way of knowing what the theme's influence is without reproducing the issue. 2. Are you sure the meta property has been succesfully registered with register_post_meta and is of the right type? 3. Why are you checking if the post type is loaded?



Whatever the theme's influence is, I've activated one which plays well with the block (which is all others). 2. WP Json shows all metas registered, including for the dropdown field. I was checking if the post type was loaded because while is was shown in the admin menu, Chromium's console was reporting that it was not available when the page with the form loaded. That was resolved and the issue of not retaining the selected option value remains.


Please don't change the question after getting an answer. Other users with a similar issue might be confused by seeing the question not match up with the answers given. It's okay to add new and relevant information, though.

That being said. Please add the code where you register your meta. One reason it might not update is because of a mismatch in the value type. The meta will only be updated after saving the post. You can check your browser console (enable XHR/fetch logs) and see the meta value being sent to the server. If possible, include that too.

The question hasn't been changed. I just updated the code and clarified in the edit what has been resolved. Re the meta wp-json shows the meta "meta": {
"_author_name": "",
"_email": "",
"_selectedGenre": ""
},
        'type' => 'string',
        'single' => true,
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field', // Added for sanitization
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'auth_callback' => function() {
            return current_user_can('edit_manuscripts');
        }
    ]

The wp-json shows the current state. But your console - when in the post editor - should show you whatever is being sent to the server whenever clicking the update button. What does the payload of the request say?

I don't know how to share the console output here (it's a lot) but basically the error is at line 35 setMeta({ ...meta, _selectedGenre: value }); "react-dom.development.js:4312 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'meta')"

Okay, that helps. That basically means that useEntityProp wasn't able to get the meta property of the current post. This could be due to the hook missing a postId argument. I've modified my answer below and included the hook to get the current postId.

I would recommend using the useEntityProp hook to get and set the meta value from your current post. The example below shows you would set that up.
import { SelectControl } from '@wordpress/components';
import { useEntityProp } from '@wordpress/core-data';
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

const FormComponent = () => {
  const postId = useSelect(
    select => select('core/editor').getCurrentPostId(),
    []
  );

  const [meta, setMeta] = useEntityProp('postType', 'manuscript', 'meta', postId);

  const handleGenreChange = (value) => {
    setMeta({
      ...meta,
      _selectedGenre: value
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className='manuscript-submission-form'>
      <SelectControl
        key='genre'
        label='Genre'
        value={meta?._selectedGenre}
        onChange={handleGenreChange}
        options={[
          { label: 'Select Genre', value: '' },
          { label: 'Fiction', value: 'fiction' },
          { label: 'Non-fiction', value: 'non-fiction' },
          { label: 'Science Fiction', value: 'sci-fi' },
          { label: 'Fantasy', value: 'fantasy' },
        ]}
        required={true}
      />
    </div>
  )
};

In your handleGenreChange you check the current property of isPostTypeLoaded as it were a ref value, but in reality it's state with a boolean value. So it will always evaluate to false and show the 'Post type not loaded yet' message.

Thanks. I wasn't notified of your answer in the 18hrs since you did. I'll give it a try tomorrow. BTW, I have been using constants because each time I try to import I get errors about React versions and WordPress, as well as errors on HTML <> tags, hence the wp.create.

The error message was added to check if the post type was not loaded even though it was displayed in the admin menu. That was resolved but maybe not in fact.

Are you using the wordpress/scripts package to build your files? If not, I'd recommend it as it works pretty much out of the box and is maintained by WP itself.
